# Split a target number into a series of numbers (recursion task)

Tags: c++, recursion, numbers

I need to write a program which generates a series of numbers that yields the target number if summed together.

Rules:

> n: Target number
>
> n=b1+b2+...+bk
>
> b1,b2,...bk>0
>
> b1>=b2>=...>=bk

For example, if you enter 7 you should get:

```
7
6 1
5 2
5 1 1
4 3
4 2 1
4 1 1 1
3 3 1
3 2 2
3 2 1 1
3 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 1
2 2 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I wrote this:

```
void generate(int n, int i){
    while(n-i>0){

        if (n-i>=i){
            cout << n-i << " " << i << endl;
            if (i>1) {
                cout << n-i << " ";
                generate(i,1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

But this results only in:

```
7 
6 1 
5 2 
5 1 1 
4 3 
4 2 1
```

I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: With a debugger you can step through the code line by line and monitor the variables in use so you can see what decisions are being made by the computer and the basis on which it is making them. Virtually all development environments come with a debugger these days, so it should just a matter of reading up on how to use whatever debugger you have.

Comment: The result is wrong because the algorithm is wrong. Your recursion is able to split the target number into maximally 3 pieces, and those splits it computes correctly. However, the algorithm cannot split your number into more than 3 pieces, and those it doesn't print.

Answer (score 1):

As @normanius implies in the comments, your algorithm doesn't backtrack correctly when finding a solution.  Additionally your condition `if (n-i>=i)` is preventing solutions initially starting with a value less than `n/2`.

I solved this by rolling my own stack and using it for backtracking:

```
void print_stack(const std::vector<int>& s)
{
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    for(; it != s.end(); ++it) std::cout << (*it) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void generate_h(int n, std::vector<int>& s)
{
    if (n == 0) print_stack(s);
    int i, ub = s.empty() ? n : s.back();
    for(i = std::min(ub, n); i > 0; --i)
    {
        s.push_back(i);
        generate_h(n-i, s);
        s.pop_back();
    }
}

void generate(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> s;
    generate_h(n, s);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    generate(7);
    return 0;
}
```